# Synonym requests: [cheating], [cheat-codes] -> [cheats]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

The tag [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats) currently has 32 questions and a wiki.  [cheating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheating) and [cheat-codes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheat-codes) have 6 and 4, respectively, and no tag wiki.

Comment: "cheating" is usually something that abuses the system (usually in the context of multiplayer games) while "codes" are almost always single-player.  This seems like a bad synonym

Comment: @Nick T — Does being single-player make it any less a cheat?  If so, wouldn't it be unnecessary to disable achievements when using cheat codes?

Comment: My point is more that one is generally seen as categorically deplorable, while the other would generate minor scoffs.

Comment: The distinction isn't even a moral one. They're two different problem spaces. One is about how to use mechanics to enhance your own enjoyment of a game, often by taking advantage of codes left in by developers for that express purpose. The other is about how to *respond to* people exploiting the game to ruin your enjoyment thereof.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, it looks like the synonym has already been made, but I'd have suggested making [cheat-codes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheat-codes) the canonical and leaving [cheating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheating) as a seperate tag.

Use the former for console nonsense, item-dupes, UUDDLRLRBA, etc., but having a separate tag for questions like [How does Valve Anti-Cheat work](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/how-does-valve-anti-cheat-vac-work) or [How do I determine if someone is cheating in Call of Duty:Black Ops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12534/how-do-i-determine-if-someone-is-cheating-in-call-of-duty-black-ops) strikes me as sensible. They are two very different categories of question.

The Tag wiki for [cheats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheats) as it stands now would be fine for a [cheat-codes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheat-codes) tag, (with some additional explication), a tag wiki for [cheating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheating) might read something like:

> This tag is for cheats conducted through exploitation or modification of game files or the use of external programs to provide an unfair gameplay advantage in competitive multiplayer games, and the various means used to counter them. Maphacks, Aimbots, Lag Switching, etc. For questions regarding other uses of the term, see [cheat-codes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheat-codes).